# Hadoop multiple -put commands slowing down

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to copy over a large amount of data (a few thousand files adding up to 19TB) to my Hadoop cluster. I'm running a bash loop over subsets of the files and the more loops I run the slower everything copies

```
for filename in /path/to/my/data/*.csv; 
    do cat $filename | ssh user@hadoop "hadoop fs -put - /path/to/new/data/$filename"; 
done
```

The same problem happens when I'm moving data around on the cluster, so I don't think it's copying over the network that is causing the problem.

Question: Can Hadoop handle multiple simultaneous `put` commands? Is what I am seeing to be expected?

**Edit**: Cluster specs: 9 servers, 4 disks per server, 24TB available on each node. About half a dozen put commands.

Comment: How many servers and disks in Hadoop cluster do you have? How many parallel `put` commands do you run?

Comment: 9 servers, 4 disks per server, 24TB available on each node. About half a dozen `put` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  HDFS write speed depends on several factors

1) Network speed

2) Disk I/O speed

3) Number of data nodes

4) Replication factor

5) Type of files - Whether large number of small files or large files

6) Namenode and Datanode Java Heap size.

7) Performance of the namenode and datanode servers.

HDFS can handle multiple read & write requests. Writing large number of small files will send write requests to the namenode for every file. The write operation will complete only after replicating to n number of nodes where n is the replication factor, so higher the replication factor, the write will take longer time.

If network, disk etc are perfect, compare the performance after increasing the heap size of namenode and datanode.